# VIM script for auto-completing Python identifier names

Tags: vim, python, autocomplete

I'm used to working with the nifty "code-intelligence" auto-completion of identifiers in Komodo IDE. In the non-graphic work environments that I still have, I'm craving for a similar capability inside VIM.

Any ideas on how to get VIM to auto-complete based on identifiers currently in the buffer and from modules imported by the current buffer?

(I'm not referring to auto-completing general Python built-ins etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try omni-completion:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1542

Answer (score 1):

Of course, one problem is that python is dynamic, so you can't really be sure what identifiers will be available outside the current file...  ;)

Anyway, [Pydiction](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850) seems to do more or less what you want?